# Is accessing a read-only member faster?

Tags: .net, clr

Is there any difference in speed when trying to read a private "readonly" instance member variable vs private instance member variable?

**Update**

The intention of this question is to get better understanding and for theoretical purpose.

Comment: I suppose reading a `Lazy` member that's been reassigned with a new instance will be slower.

Comment: Do you have a performance problem you think is related to this, or is this only theoretical?

Comment: @Magnus for Theoretical and better understanding.

Comment: @Ramesh I doubt it, but isn't it mostly irrelevant? A field is either `readonly` or it isn't; it's not like you could go marking mutable fields `readonly` for a performance gain...

Comment: @veredesmarald The question is to see whether the Runtime has the capability to cache this value and be faster as it is not going to change.

Comment: @Ramesh I understand the question, I'm saying even if it were faster (which I doubt) there is nothing you can do with that information anyway, since all your `readonly` fields should already be marked `readonly`, and the others can't be.

Answer (score 1):

There is no performance difference. Changing to 'const' would gain some performance though. All of this is exquisitely desribed in this nice article;

http://www.dotnetperls.com/readonly

Comment: Thanks @Ivo. I understad const keyword is used for marking compile time constants which are replace with actual value during compilation, where as readonly fields are runtime constants.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have this code:

```
void Main()
{
    Test t = new Test();
    t.Check();
}

public class Test
{
    private readonly int  num = 10;
    private int num1 = 50;

    public void Check()
    {
        int a = num1;
        int b = num;
    }
}
```

Now the generated MSIL code is the following

```
IL_0001:  newobj      UserQuery+Test..ctor
IL_0006:  stloc.0     
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     
IL_0008:  callvirt    UserQuery+Test.Check

Test.Check:
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldarg.0     
IL_0002:  ldfld       UserQuery+Test.num1
IL_0007:  stloc.0     
IL_0008:  ldarg.0     
IL_0009:  ldfld       UserQuery+Test.num
IL_000E:  stloc.1     
IL_000F:  ret         

Test..ctor:
IL_0000:  ldarg.0     
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.s    0A 
IL_0003:  stfld       UserQuery+Test.num
IL_0008:  ldarg.0     
IL_0009:  ldc.i4.s    32 
IL_000B:  stfld       UserQuery+Test.num1
IL_0010:  ldarg.0     
IL_0011:  call        System.Object..ctor
IL_0016:  nop         
IL_0017:  ret
```

So I see that readonly is a language specific keyword used to express a programming concept.
It is the compiler, when it builds your code, that enforce the readonly rules.
From the point of view of generated code there is no difference. –

Comment: interesting. I just googled and found www.owasp.org/index.php/CSharp_readonly_modifier_is_not_inforced_by_the_CLR_(when_in_Full_Trust) which tells, it is enforced in partial trust and not by full trust in CLR.